# how to know which remote branch that my local branch is merged into

Tags: git

I have a local branch and create a pull request, but I do not know if it is accepted and merged, and which remote branch it is merged into.

How can I know that?

I know through gitk or SourceTree we might see the result.

But how to achieve it by command line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose the local branch is `foo`.

```
git fetch
git branch -r --contains foo
```

`git fetch` updates the tracking branches like `origin/foo`.

`git branch -r --contains foo` lists all the tracking branches (`-r`) that have merged `foo` (`--contains foo`).

If a tracking branch `origin/bar` is in the output, then we know the branch `bar` in the remote repository has merged `foo`.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your answer